# Boomerang for Outlook?

Tags: email, outlook

I absolutely love the app Boomerang for Gmail. It made me so much more productive. Unfortunately, at work I'm on outlook (part of Office 365 Business) and Boomerang is not available for that. Boomerang for Outlook exists but only works in the web app with an outlook account.

The app for gmail: http://www.boomeranggmail.com/

Main features:

```
E-mail reminders (email returns after x days without reply)
Return an email to your inbox at a a specific time (snooze email)
Mailbox Pauze
Send later ...
```

Is there an alternative that works with Outlook?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. For those who don't know Boomerang: What makes it special that you want? On what OS should it run? What is your price limit if it comes to paid software?

Answer (score 1):

[SalesHandy](https://www.saleshandy.com/) has Email tracking, Email Scheduling, Reply Tracking, Mail Merge, Document, Attachment tracking, etc. They have an Outlook plugin.
[ToutApp](https://www1.toutapp.com/outlook-integration/) also has a lot of features.

Comment: Unfortunately that only works if you use an outlook mail account.

Comment: @WVM, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though some time has passed since you asked your question, I can still gladly recommend using Sellizer. As a comprehensive email tracking tool, Sellizer is equipped not only with the functions that you mentioned.

Would you like to find out more about Sellizer, here you go: https://www.sellizer.io.

Good luck :)

Comment: Welcome Kacper!  Do you have any affiliation with this product?  Thanks!